# Python IF statement to return 'True' if no link found using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm quite new to Python and can usually figure out issues with some scouring, but with this I'm stumped, a website I frequent clandestinely releases products on their shop page, when they are sold out they are no longer visible, they don't just say sold out, they are removed, so their are no links in the list element (not sure if using the term element correctly there).

I have managed to use beautifulsoup to extract when there is a link, but the majority of the time there isn't one, I'm now trying to use a 'while True' and 'IF' statement to routinely check if a link isn't there, if there is no link, recheck after some time, but I cannot get python to print a True result when no link is returned and I'm not sure why.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

list = soup.find('div', class_='list-grid')
for link in list.find_all('a'):
    item = (link.get('href'))

    if link is NoneType:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

I've tried link == "", link is "", link is None, link is NoneType (though I'm not sure the difference) and all the same with the 'item' variable instead, but when no link is returned the if statement returns no value, no True or False, it's like it ignores the statement entirely even though it's a yes/no question.

Comment: Realistically, why would `link` be `None` within a `for link in...` loop...? Are you expecting the result of `list.find_all('a')` to include *some* items which are `None`, and some which are not `None`? I can't say for 100% certain whether that would actually possible in practice using BS4 but would seem to me quite the anti-pattern. Do you mean to be checking whether `item` is `None`? That would seem more logical to me...

Comment: Also - it's a bad idea to select variable names (namely `list`) which coincide directly with built-in Python classes. This can cause rather unexpected behaviors later on.

Comment: Presumably, if there are no `<a>` links then `list.find_all('a')` returns an empty list and nothing in your for loop executes. Save the result as a local variable e.g. `links` then test its length. Also, don't use the name `list` for a variable because it shadows a Python built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're really only concerned with whether or not the call to `list.find_all('a')` actually returns any matching elements, in which case you can do away with the loop entirely and simply test the length of the list that's returned by Beautiful Soup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

list = soup.find('div', class_='list-grid')

if len(list.find_all('a')) > 0:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

This solution will be vastly more performant in production and reduces the verbosity of your check significantly.

Answer (score 0):

one fast fix to your code is, pretty self explanatory. Note that the final IF block is not part of the FOR loop:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html5lib')

link_found = False

list = soup.find('div', class_='list-grid')
for link in list.find_all('a'):
    link_found = True
    .. your code logic here

if link_found:
    print("true")
else:
    print("false")
```

Comment: Why loop all items in `list.find_all('a')` if `link_found = len(list.find_all('a')) > 0` would be *much* faster and less verbose? Do away with the loop entirely if there's no value or requirement for reading/operating on individual list members.

Comment: true that, thats why i characterized it a `fast fix` :) assuming there are not many iterations in the for loop both can be fine answers